# How to Restart nodeJS screen app without reboot PC

Tags: node.js

I trying to restart `nodejs` app which is running in background `screen` app.
But here i can't do these without reboot my PC. I used `forever` module but it's start when i reboot my PC but I actually want one button on web-page and when I click on that automatically start node app `without` restart my PC.

Any One have iDEA about these please let me guide what to Do ?

NOTE : `without reboot my system working`

Comment: Why do you need to restart your PC to restart the Node server?

Comment: I can easily do with cmd to kill process. But if non-technical will use these than they just need to press one button on web page and node server kill and auto start without reboot PC. In `forever` module need to reboot PC for start app again without open cmd

Comment: @higunjan Have you ever tried PM2 ?

Comment: How do you start your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute commands from nodejs like this :

**nodejs**

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec('forever restart', function callback(error, stdout, stderr) {
    // console.log(stdout);
});
```